# Fill comboBox from stored procedure with String Exec

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure with String Exec

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetZInfo]
@RegID int = 4
AS

DECLARE @DB NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_' + CAST(@RegID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @exec NVARCHAR(MAX) =' 
select z.ZIndex, z.LastZMade, z.Zrange,z.LastModified 
FROM [Server\SQL].'+@DB+'.dbo.ZEntrytable z 
WHERE z.LastZMade > (DATEADD(HH,6,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0))) 
ORDER BY z.ZIndex DESC
'

EXEC (@exec)
```

SQL Result

[image]

i want to get the SQL Result to C# comboBox

```
comboBoxZinfo.Items.Clear();

Int32 RegIDxml;
RegIDxml = Int32.Parse(GetRegIDxml());

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetZInfo", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RegID", RegIDxml)); //RegID.text
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    comboBoxZinfo.Items.Add(dr["ZIndex"].ToString());
}

conn.Close();
```

**It does not work with the `Exec` but if I use simple select statement then it works**

Simple select statement is *Working*:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetZInfo]
@RegID int = 4
AS
select gci.FranchisesName from dbo.GetClientInfo gci
```

Comment: Any error you are getting ?? It seems that both the statements are different.. One is a simple select statement and the other one is a select statement with where clause.

Comment: `It does not work` what does it mean?

Comment: You seem to be missing a dot: `[Server\SQL]'+@DB` --> `[Server\SQL].'+@DB`

Comment: *"It still does not work"* then tell us the error. "still" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Now I understand the problem,
When I use same server it works, only I Use to another server to get the information that is not working properly

Comment: "It does not work" is the single most useless phrase heard around online technical forums. You need to include the error message or an explanation of **what** isn't working. Otherwise the people trying to help you have to guess. Stop making us guess, provide some details and let us help you.

Comment: I've now voted to close this as off topic: specifically *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"*

Comment: I see you have deleted all your "doesn't work" comments but you still haven't told us what the issue is. My guess is you don't have linked servers established. The error message would make short work of this.

Comment: how i get the error?

Comment: This should help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-and-fix-code-errors?view=vs-2017 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017

Comment: i don't get error, the i jest do'nt get info to the C#, but when i run th SP in SQL i get Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
da.Fill(dt);
comboBoxZinfo.DataSource = dt;
comboBoxZinfo.DisplayMember = "ZIndex";
comboBoxZinfo.ValueMember = "ZIndex";
```